# Use grep to search for multiple strings, but keep order

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm looking for a way to use grep to search for multiple strings but keep the same order.  So, for example, if I have this command:

```
egrep '(string1|string2|string3)' /some/file.txt
```

I may return:

```
string2
string1
string3
```

Depending on the order they are in the file.  What I need it to is no matter where in the file the strings are found they always return:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

Or if not found found it returns nothing, but the order is still maintained:

```
string1
string3
```

Comment: Then you need to search for them one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output can be ordered (i.e. string1 < string2 < string3) you can do the following:

```
egrep '(string1|string2|string3)' /some/file.txt | sort
```

If it cannot be ordered, or search for them with three different grep:

```
egrep 'string1' /some/file.txt
egrep 'string2' /some/file.txt
egrep 'string3' /some/file.txt
```

or use an array and a for loop:

```
stringsToSearch=(string1 string2 string3)

for item in ${stringsToSearch[*]}
do
egrep '$item' /some/file.txt
done
```

Comment: Out of all the suggestions your loop was the best and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Scan once, then print matches for each expression in turn. If an input matches multiple expressions, it is listed in the first set that matched.

I'm using colon as expression delimiter; obviously, feel free to change as you see fit.

```
awk -v 'expr=string1:string2:string3' '
    BEGIN { n=split(expr, e, /:/);
      for(i=i; i<=n; ++i) m[i]="" }
    { for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) if ($0 ~ e[i]) {
      m[i]=m[i] $0 ORS; next } }
    END { for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) printf m[i] }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

How to automate doing it one at a time:

echo "string1 string2 string3" | xargs -n 1 -J % egrep % /some/file.txt